# Adsense ad not showing up, just a blank div, how do I properly fix this

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, adsense

So I've been trying to get AdSense ads to work for about a year now, both on WordPress and what I am currently doing which is just a simple HTML/CSS website.

First I tried it out on my main website and nothing showed up I was like hm.. Maybe something is blocking it, maybe it is hidden. So I created the most simple webpage there is and added my AdSense script to it and its still just blank.
I tried it with and without AdBlock, different browsers and such.
And just to throw it out there, the xx-xxx etc is all replaced with the real information.

Why is it just blank? I have a verified account, the ads status is new. I tried it with an active one as well, it didn't make any difference.
How do I properly deal with this issue?

```
<html>
    <head>
        Header Part
        <title>Example HTML-page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        This is the body
        <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
        <!-- secondAd -->
        <ins class="adsbygoogle"
             style="display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px"
             data-ad-client="xx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
             data-ad-slot="xxxxxxxxx"></ins>
        <script>
            (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens when you open your devtools/console? Any messages?

Comment: No error messages and this is what it looks like https://i.imgur.com/cUqcucH.png

Comment: **Adblockers** are usually the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Is the ad present in the first place? Have you whitelisted your IP.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/cUqcucH.png
That's what it looks like and I dont think im whitelisted, I tried sending my webpage to a couple of friends, they cant see it either

Comment: @JordanJones Can you share the console log. what you shared above is the inspect element part. The tab next to the one which you opened in https://i.imgur.com/cUqcucH.png